# How do I access an abstract class' Hashmap?

Tags: java, class, hashmap, abstract

I have two classes. One is a public class and the other is an abstract class with HashMap of objects. How do I call the abstract class' HashMap`.get(string)` method from my public class? I am new to Java and may be having this problem because I am not understanding how to setup my java files correctly.

Here are sections of my two classes...(in same file `Evaluator.java`)

```
    public class  Evaluator {
     ...code        
     public int eval (String expr) {
        Operator newOpr = (Operator) operators.get(tok);
     }
    ... more code
    } 



//abstract class

    abstract class Operator {

        Operator(){
        HashMap operators = new HashMap();
        operators.put("+",new AdditionOperator()); 
        operators.put("-",new SubtractionOperator());
        }

        abstract int priority();

        static boolean check(String tok){
        return true;
        }   

        abstract Operand execute(Operand opd1, Operand opd2);

    }

    //priority 2, addition and subtraction
    class AdditionOperator extends Operator{
        @Override 
        int priority(){
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public Operand execute (Operand op1, Operand op2){
          ...code
        }

    }
```

Comment: Does your abstract class have a method that exposes access to the `HashMap` or to its get method?  It needs one.

Comment: Can you post the code of your classes?

Comment: If you can, make the hashMap (theMap) static. Otherwise, you'll have to subclass it to be able to access its instance methods.

Comment: the abstract method does not have a get. it is an class called Operator that is used to be extended to create operator objects such as AdditionOperator or SubtractionOperator.

Comment: I edited my comment. Normally, if you have an abstract class, you'll want to subclass it.

Comment: What does the hashmap represents?

Comment: hashmap is a map of operators linked to the operator symbols
example i would store a subclass object of operator like the addition operator with the symbol "+"

Comment: I would say that the HashMap is in the wrong class. In this way your Hashmap will have to be either a static field or a public field.

You don't even need a Operator Abstract class in my opinion. A interface would do the job and the hashmap could be in a class called OperatorFactory and only expose a public method Operator create(string operator). In this way your Evaluator class don't even need to know what is the internal data structure the other classes are using.

Comment: Looks like you need a factory. Why don't you just implement the factory pattern? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29

Comment: in this case, can i not access the HashMap from that scope? it seems to not know that the HashMap "operators" exists in my abstract class.

Comment: My question was originally regarding the combination of a HashMap and an abstract classes , so getting rid of my abstract class is not ideal.

Comment: You are right. The answer is make The HasMap either static field or public. But this go agains the idea of OOP of expose behavior and hide implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome in the java world !
give-us the code of your two Class(the public and the abstract) if you want a preciseanswer.

You probably need to create a not abstract class  who extends the abstract Class to call the method.

Comment: okay will post this code. I did not want to post my code because it would be basically asking for debugging help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just call a method on an abstract class. You need an instance of the class. Since the class is abstract, you'll have to make a concrete class for it to get the method.

```
class Foo extends AbstractFoo
{
    ... Implement any required methods ...
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
Foo bar = new Foo();
bar.get("thing");
```

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to the question is make your HashMap either a public field or static.

```
abstract class Operator {
        public static HashMap operators;
        Operator(){
          Operator.operators = new HashMap();
          Operator.operators.put("+",new AdditionOperator()); 
          Operator.operators.put("-",new SubtractionOperator());
        }
    }

public class  Evaluator {
 ...code        
 public int eval (String expr)
    Operator newOpr = (Operator) Operator.operators.get(tok);
 }
 ... more code
}
```

I would say that the HashMap is in the wrong class. In this way your HashMap will have to be either a static field or a public field. You don't even need a Operator Abstract class in my opinion. A interface would do the job and the HashMap could be in a class called OperatorFactory and only expose a public method Operator create(string operator). In this way your Evaluator class don't even need to know what is the internal data structure the other classes are using.

```
interface Operator(){

     public Operand execute(Operator op1, Operator op2);
}

public class AdditionOperator implements Operator{
    public Operand execute(Operand op1, Operand op2){
        return op1;
    }

}

public class OperatorFactory(){
    //Could use a HasMap internally in this class but it doesn't matter 
    //to the other classes
    public Operator crate(string operator){
        if( operator == "+")
           return new AdditionOperator();
    }

}

 public class  Evaluator {
    ...code        
    OperatorFactory operatorFactory;
    public Evaluator(OperatorFactory operatorFactory){
       operatorFactory = operatorFactory;
    }
    public int eval (String expr) {
       Operator newOpr = operatorFactory.create(tok);
    }
    ... more code
 }
```